# Doubts about running the background execution limit in Android Oreo

Tags: android, location, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I have an Android application that has a background service, which works every 5 minutes. It turns on the GPS and compares with the starting position, if you're on a trip (checking speed and distance), start the App to track and analyze how the driver is driving.

This application works and is in the store, but I am upgrading it to Android Oreo, and I'm not sure how it will work this service policy in SO background Li on the subject and I saw that Android will have a window where background services goes but I do not know how the kind of service I need will behave.

Comment: Please explain in detail what "works every 5 minutes" means. Are you using `AlarmManager` for this? `JobScheduler`? Something else?

Comment: It is a Service that has a timer for every 5 minutes to listen to the GPS and check if you are on a trip. I am updating this code and I will use the Firebase JobScheduler. But my question is how this limitation of Android Oreo will work, as I'm reading a lot of talking material that will allow background access only a few times per hour.

Comment: "It is a Service that has a timer for every 5 minutes to listen to the GPS" -- please do not do that. **Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user**. Watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user. You are tying up system RAM that the user does not have much of and would really appreciate using for other purposes. Your primary Android 8.0 problem is that [you will not get location data very much in the background](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html).

Comment: In fact I have broken this project to update and restructure, so I will change the whole implementation. I read the link on Background Location Limitation on Android Oreo that you passed me, and I think the best way for me to get the new location services is by using [GeofencingClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient). When the device leaves the location, it checks if it is a trip, and starts capturing the data for the trip evaluation in the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JobIntentService of support library to replace intent service.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html

Comment: I already read about JobIntentService and chose to use the JobScheduler from [Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) because it is compatible with all versions of Android since API level 9+.

Comment: In older versions, JobIntentService uses traditional IntentService for compatibility. So that you can blindly rely on this API. But in the case of JobScheduler from firebase, you should properly test on all devices. Anyways, it's your decision. Thanks.